# BugBridger - A stack overflow mobile app to solve all of your questions

Tags: app, android, stackoverflow

### Screenshot / Code Snippet

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

### About

- Discover featured questions effortlessly on the home tab, elegantly presented in card format.
- Each question card provides essential details such as the question title, description, tags, and key statistics like view count, answer count, and votes.
- Get insights into the user who posted the question, with the option to tap for in-depth user information, including their name, joining date, reputation, and badges.
- Effortlessly search for specific questions using the search bar, complete with advanced search filters and sorting options for tailored results.
- Simply tap on any question card to access the dedicated question screen, offering comprehensive information about the question and all associated answers.
- Enjoy proper code and text formatting with Markdown support, ensuring readability of coding blocks.
- Quickly identify accepted answers for optimal problem-solving.
- Explore the entire Stack Overflow repository, including both questions and answers, with a single button press.
- Discover a collection of articles from Stack Overflow within the dedicated "Articles" tab, with the added convenience of sorting options.

#### Download

[Download from here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Qa8uFZykP_vbu6clscmYC0bRwJ7JNGpH/view?usp=share_link)

#### Platform

BugBridger app works on **Android** smartphones.

### Contact

**Brijen Makwana** created this app. You can see his [GitHub](https://github.com/BrijenMakwana) profile.

### Code

This mobile app is built with these tech stacks:

- React Native
- Expo 49
- Typescript
- tamagui
- expo-router
- Stack Exchange API
- Shopify Flashlist and MasonryFlashList

You can see the **code** on this [GitHub repo](https://github.com/BrijenMakwana/BugBridger)

Comment: Any chance of putting it on google play or f droid?

Comment: you can download it from here: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1QdhMjRzOS3kFXa8eRT9H89JI1ETOfQEi